# math in MS Calibri

Tags: fontspec, sans-serif, mathematics

I have to typeset a document in Calibri upright letters. There is a problem with mathematics: When I typeset the following minimal-example, letters are right Calibri, but numbers are italic by default. Numbers in equations should be upright by default. So what can I do? By the way, I compile with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\sansmath
\begin{document}
$A=3$
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, `fontspec` sets the main encoding to Unicode, so you shouldn't use `fontenc` too.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend `unicode-math` whenever you aren't forced to use the legacy encodings.  I particularly recommend that over mixing the modern and legacy packages.  This scales the fonts you select automatically so that their heights, at least, match.  It supports both Unicode input and output that you can copy and paste.  It even lets you use the Greek letters of Calibri.

Warning: I'm not currently on my Windows box, so I wasn't able to test this for you, but it works with different fonts.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Or mathtools    
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Or polyglossia

\setmainfont{Calibri}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\setmathfont[slash-delimiter=frac]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Calibri}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Calibri Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Calibri Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Calibri Bold Italic}

\setoperatorfont\normalfont % For log, sin, cos, etc.

\begin{document}
$A=3$
\end{document}
```

Here is a version using Carlito and other free fonts.  It also demonstrates how you can use some of the math symbols your text font supports in math mode.  (The list of symbols in Calibri will be different, and also, you should be alert to inconsistencies such as one of <, ≮, ≤, ≦, etc. not matching the others, if you use one of them that you didn’t change to the same font.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Or polyglossia

\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up,"002B,"002D,`±,`×,`·,`÷,`¬,`∂,`∆,`∕,`∞,`⌐}]{Carlito}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Carlito Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Carlito Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Carlito Bold Italic}

\setoperatorfont\normalfont % For log, sin, cos, etc.

\begin{document}
Foo bar baz.

$A \log b = 3$
\end{document}
```

[image: Carlito]

**Edit:** In the comments, you indicate that you wanted the math letters to be italicized.  If so, delete the `[math-style=upright]` option to the `unicode-math` package, or change it to `[math-style=ISO]` if you want italic uppercase Greek letters as well.  (TeX doesn’t do that by default only because legacy math fonts usually didn’t have those letters.)

Comment: If I use `\mathbf{b}` rather than `b`, say, I get Latin Modern Roman bold. (`unicode-math` is very buggy in my experience. At least the `range` stuff really doesn't work.)

Comment: @cfr Yeah, `\symbfup` works and the `mathbf=sym` package option is a workaround to that. Still a WIP, I agree, but very usable already.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you, it works fine on my Window-Computer. The unicode-version I need is without the upright option. Letters should be italic, only numbers should be upright by default.

Comment: @Florian Okay. In that case, either remove the `[math-style=upright]` option to the package, as you've done, or change it to `[math-style=ISO]` if you also want uppercase Greek letters to be italicized. By default, they aren't, only because legacy math fonts usually didn't include them.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] as suggested by Davislor, both `fontspec` and `mathspec` are not needed here

A solution is to use the `mathspec` package and set your math fonts manually. I do not have access to Calibri right now, so this MWE is with Roboto, but it should work with Calibri too

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\sansmath

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto} 

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin){Roboto}


\begin{document}
Text mode gives A=3 \\
Math mode gives $A=3$ \\
Greeks are still in Euler : $\Omega = \rho / \rho_{crit.}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest section 4 of the [mathspec manual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdfcracker.com) for more options, where you will find how to also make Latin characters upright as well if that's what you want. Using `mathspec` to set your Greek math font would also probably be more elegant.

Comment: Also a good answer. Suggestion: `mathspec` automatically includes `fontspec`, and you shouldn't load both `fontspec` and `fontenc`, so you can take both those packages out of the template.

Comment: Additionally, `\setmathfont` is available as an undocumented alias, but the `mathspec` command, according to the manual, is `\setmathsfont`. I personally prefer `\setmathsfont` for `mathspec`, since there is a different `\setmathfont` in `unicode-math`. Spelling the commands differently avoids confusion.

Comment: That's true. I tend to forget this and use `[no-math]{fontspec}` and then `mathspec` because of a different use case - thank you for the reminder, I'll edit. No excuse for `fontenc` though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fira Math is available [here](http://latex.userpage.fu-berlin.de/FiraMath-Regular.otf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmathfont[mathrm=sym]{Fira Math}
%\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenic Math}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
Some math in Sans Serif
$A=3$ 
$\Omega = \rho / \rho_{\text{crit.}}$   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the problem that the OP needs upright letters and numbers? That's how I read the question.

Comment: @cfr That was how I read it too. But the OP clarified in a comment that the math letters should be italic.

Comment: @Davislor Oh, I see. I thought numbers in maths were upright by default :-). I guess that's font-dependent.

Comment: @cfr Same. Some package must've changed it.