# New fontspec gives problem with xelatex and Calibri

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Running the MWE below runs correct with fontspec 2.6l (rev 49739 in Texlive 2018/Win 7) but gives an error with fontspec 2.7 (rev 49809)

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = nl_NL
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
%% Find out what engine we're running...
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

%% Different setup for xe
\ifxetex
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439998/math-in-ms-calibri/440080
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathfont[slash-delimiter=frac]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Calibri}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Calibri Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Calibri Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Calibri Bold Italic}
\setoperatorfont\normalfont % For log, sin, cos, etc.
\else
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nimbusmono}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\fi

\begin{document}

Text

\end{document}
```

Error given:

```
<snip>
Package fontspec Warning: Font "Calibri" does not contain requested Script "".


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.22 \setmathfont
                 [range=it]{Calibri Italic}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
</snip>
```

So what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I've let Will know: I've seen this also with the LaTeX3 test suite, but that was with a CJK font.

Comment: Sorry about this, update is on its way to CTAN as we speak.

Comment: When there are clear package update bugs like this it's usually better to go straight to the package on GitHub rather than ask a question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that is an bug report for an bug meanwhile resolved ...